# How can I use the group method on this regex code when I'm getting a callable iterator issue?

Tags: python, regex, attributeerror

So I'm trying to solve some code problems on the 30 days of code hackerrank challenges. I have to return the first names of inputs if they have an email which is gmail.com. So for example the input might be:

(The number specifies the number of input lines for the program.)

```
6
riya riya@gmail.com
julia julia@julia.me
julia sjulia@gmail.com
julia julia@gmail.com
samantha samantha@gmail.com
tanya tanya@gmail.com
```

and the output would look like

```
riya
julia
julia
samantha
tanya
```

I wrote the following code to try and handle this:

```py
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input().strip())
    
    pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]@gmail\.com)')

    for N_itr in range(N):
        first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

        firstName = first_multiple_input[0]

        emailID = first_multiple_input[1]
        
        matches = pattern.finditer(emailID)
        
        if matches.group(0):
            print(firstName)
```

but when I run the code I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 25, in <module>
    if matches.group(0):
AttributeError: 'callable_iterator' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I looked at similar problems like this on Stack Overflow but I couldn't understand the answers, this is my first time using regex and I'm working from videos I've watched online (since I'm self taught). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `re.finditer` returns the match data object iterator and only a match object contains the `.group()` method. Get the match data object first. Or use `re.search` to just get the first match. Or, here, you may simply split the strings.

Comment: You also have to repeat the character class or else you will match a single character `([a-zA-Z]+)@gmail\.com`

Comment: Checking whether there is at least one alphabetic before `@` is actually sufficient if that's what you specifically care about, though like I point out in my answer, there are other characters you should probably look for too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex (or `math`, or `random`, or `os`) here.

```py
import sys

number = int(sys.stdin.__next__())

for idx, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if idx > number:
        break
    if '@gmail.com' not in line:
        next
    print(line.split()[0])
```

This is not *precisely* equivalent to your code, because we don't check what's before the `@` character.  If you wanted to do that, you should really check what Gmail permits (for example, I think they will allow numbers there, and probably a dot, and possibly some other characters like underscores etc).

If you really wanted to use a regex, probably don't use `finditer`, which returns a *list* of `match` objects. If you only care about the first match, simply use `re.search()` instead; then, the result will be a `match` object if there was a match, and you can call its `.group()` method.

This is also not precisely equivalent to your code, in that it will not fail if there are fewer input lines than what the first line promised. Adding a check for that should be easy, and probably a good exercise.

If your file contains no functions, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` check is pointless.  Its purpose is to allow another Python module to `import` this one, but if it doesn't contain anything which can usefully be `import`ed, you will never want to do that anyway. (In some more detail, when you `import` this file, `__name__` will not be `__main__`, and so all that code will simply be discarded. You want to put as little as possible in there, and if you care about code reusability, put all the useful code in classes and functions.)